# weak forms of associativity in "vector spaces".

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $(V, \mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ satisfies all the axioms of a vector
space but (not necessarily) the associativity of the addition. Suppose that an
inner product is defined on $V$ (usual axioms make sense if associativity is
not assumed).

After that, assume that one can prove that associativity holds for orthogonal vectors,
i.e., that
$$ u_1 + (u_2 + u_3) = (u_1 + u_2) + u_3 $$
whenever $u_1, u_2, u_3 \in V$ and $u_i \cdot u_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$. Can we
conclude that $V$ is a vector space, i.e., that associativity is guaranteed on
all vectors?

**Why such a question?** When one wants to convince graphically that associativity
holds for Euclidean vectors in space, the picture is messy for vectors
in general position. But the picture can convince anyone as soon as one can consider only orthogonal vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you give yourself the inner product, the associativity of addition is an immediate result by computing
$$
\lVert((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rVert^2=
\langle ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3)), ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle
$$
and peel the parentheses
\begin{align*}
RHS&=\langle (v_1+v_2)+v_3, ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle\\
&\quad-\langle v_1+(v_2+v_3),((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle\\
&=[\langle v_1+v_2, ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle+\langle v_3, ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle]\\
&\quad-[\langle v_1,((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle+\langle v_2+v_3, ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle]\\
&=\left[\sum_{i=1}^3\langle v_i, ((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle\right]\\
&\quad-\left[\sum_{i=1}^3\langle v_i,((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))\rangle\right]\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
So $((v_1+v_2)+v_3)-(v_1+(v_2+v_3))=0$, i.e., $(v_1+v_2)+v_3=v_1+(v_2+v_3)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your answer, I realize that what I had in mind was not properly modeled by my question. But your answer helps me understand how to fix it. Thanks! (PS What I mean is that in relation to "why such a question" I just wanted to rely on the notion of orthogonality, and to introduce an inner product would require motivating it graphically and also showing graphically that it is bilinear. The goal would be to show associativity only on what appears drawn orthogonal and then to say that the more general case follows by algebra (no need to do pictures).